# How to efficiently extract numbers from text in a data.table column in R

Tags: r, regex, data.table, stringr, kaggle

I'm just learning R for data science, and used these few lines to extract numbers from data (using data.table):

```
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
prods[, weights := str_extract(NombreProducto, "([0-9]+)[kgKG]+")]
prods[, weights := str_extract(weights, "[0-9]+")]
prods[, weights := as.numeric(weights)]
```

Here's an example of the 'NombreProducto' field I want to extract numbers/text from:

```
"Tostado 210g CU BIM 1182"
```

Is there an easy way to do this in a succinct one-liner?  I tried

```
prods[, weights := str_match(NombreProducto, "([0-9]+)[kgKG]+")[2]]
```

but it set everything in the 'weights' column to the first result from the data.table.  This is from the Grupo Bimbo Kaggle competition by the way.

Comment: It is not clear what you really wanted.

Comment: I want the first chunk of code in one line.

Comment: Try `prods[, weights := as.numeric(str_extract(NombreProducto, "([0-9]+)(?=(kg|KG))"))]`

Answer (score 3):

Without using `stringr`, you could just use `sub` with `".*?(\\d+)[kgKG].*"` and back reference:

```
s = "Tostado 210g CU BIM 1182"

sub(".*?(\\d+)[kgKG].*", "\\1", s)
# [1] "210"
```

- use `(\\d+)[kgKG]` to match digits followed by `k, K, g, G` letters;
- specify `.*` before and after the pattern so that strings other than the pattern can be removed;
- use `?` on the first `.*` to make the match unready so that all the three digits will be kept;
- use `\\1` to refer the capture group `(\\d+)`;

Answer (score 2):

We can use this with `stringr` in a single line using regex lookarounds.

```
prods[, weights := as.numeric(str_extract(NombreProducto, "([0-9]+)(?=[kgKG])"))]
```